# Browser history needs a DOM in my tests with jest

Tags: unit-testing, testing, dom, jestjs, ts-jest

When I try to test my sagas I get the following error:

> Invariant failed: Browser history needs a DOM

and test suite failed to run

It happens because I use function redirectTo() in my sagas
This function exports from this file:

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

export const history = createHistory();

export const redirectTo = (path: string): void => {
  history.push(path);
};
```

How can I solve this problem? I need emulate DOM?

This error occurs even if I use saga which does not contain redirectTo() function

Comment: Which line throws this error. Create a minimal, reproducible example

Comment: export const history = createHistory(); - this line
history needs a DOM error occurs when I call createHistory()

Answer (score 1):

according to JEST [documentation](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup/#:%7E:text=If%20you%27re%20using%20the%20Jest%20testing%20framework%20version,features%20and%20fixes%2C%20required%20by%20React%20Testing%20Library.) you need to set the testEnvironment variable to jsdom by adding it to jest.config file for all tests or a comment in the .spec file for the single suite

For single file add this comment at the top:

```
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */
```

or to set the jsdom environment for all tests add this:

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
   // ... other options ...
}
```